# I am trying to unnest a columns on a cognos report

Tags: database-design, nodes, edit, cognos, unnest

I have two columns are nested, one is a state code and the other is a prod code (see below)  I need to put that "state CO, OK, NM" in each row for the column? Same for the product code ex: 96 for each row.  How do I un nest the column? Thank you for your help.

| Prod # | State AB |
| --- | --- |
| 96 | CO |
|  |  |

I am new to cognos building reports.  i am not sure how/where/to find the table to resolve the issue

Comment: Try this.  Click on the product code (you want as the column) and there should be a hot bar menu (cut, paste, etc) at the end of the hotbar menu are three dots (if you mouse over it will say more).  From the more menu select Pivot List to Crosstab.  You may have to hide properties to see the more menu.  Let me know if that is what you wanted